# Find Maximum of a function with restraint

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f(x,y,z):=z^4(x^2 −xy+y^2)+z^2(x^4 +y^4)$
and let $A ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3$ be the convex polyhedron with vertices (1, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 3), and (4, 4, 0). Find $sup_A f$.

I understand how to use lagrange multipliers on restraints and boundaries and have to check if jacobian matrix includes 0 or not correct? but I am not sure how to apply here. Thanks.

Comment: The most elementary method is to look for interior critical points (the gradient is zero) and critical points on the boundary (gradients of the objective function and the active constraints are linearly dependent). Then compare the values.

Comment: is there any shortcuts here? thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by shortcuts. You can always do some equivalent transform. For example, you can represent a point in the polyhedron as a generic convex combination of the vertices and then optimize over a simplex. Otherwise, you can split the problem and maximize first over some variables and then over the others. There are very many tricks that may (or may not) give a simpler solution.